# Latest jqModal release: "live" link triggers won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqmodal

With the latest jqModal release (+r14), I'm having an issue with the new feature of live links. Whenever the live-loaded trigger link is clicked on, it redirects to the HREF instead of loading it via AJAX. How can I make it behave normally?

I've searched around and other people seem to have this issue, but it's gone unresolved.

```
$('a.modal-product-trigger').live('click', function(){
    $('#modal-product').jqmShow(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not particularly familiar with jqModal, but try canceling the event:

```
$('a.modal-product-trigger').live('click', function(){
        $('#modal-product').jqmShow(this);
        return false;   
});
```

If you don't do this the event will go through with its default action, which is to act as a regular link.